# Add Many-to-Many Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I've got a question:

I have 3 tables:

1. Users
2. Menu
3. UserMenu

UserMenu contains IdMenu and IdUser.

In My DataModel Entity Framework 4.0, I'm filling my User Model and filling User.Menu (Menu is Navigation Properties) with an existing Menu of my table Menu.

I have to save User and Save each related menu item in UserMenu table.

I get the following exception:

> The ObjectStateManager does not contain an ObjectStateEntry with a
>   reference to an object of type 'SGGED.Model.Menu'.

**Code**

```
Users objUser = new Users();

objUser.name = itemUsers.name.Trim();
objUser.email = itemUsers.email.Trim();
objUser.password = Util.HashString("12345");
objUser.effdt = DateTime.Now;

objData.Users.AddObject(objUser);

foreach (var itemMenu in itemUsers.Menu)
{
    objData.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(itemMenu, EntityState.Unchanged);
}

affRows = objData.SaveChanges();
```

Whats the way to handle this issue?

Best Regards,

Miltom Camara

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post on many-to-many relationships:

[Many to Many Relationships with EF](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2012/06/13/many-to-many-relationships-with-ef.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that the items in `itemUsers.Menu` do not exist in your current objData context.  This could be either that you loaded them from another context object, or they have been created in code but never added to the objData.Menus set.